# Trouble Showing Value of SFDC Conversion in AdWords

Tags: google-ads-api, conversion-tracking

[Screenshots and similar explanation found at my post in the AdWords community help forum](https://www.en.advertisercommunity.com/t5/AdWords-Tracking-and-Reporting/Delay-in-AdWords-Conversion-Value/td-p/872024)

Whereas most, usual AdWords conversions center around an event happening on your site (often via Google Analytics), Google now (as of ~6 months ago, I believe) offers the ability to track conversions that occur in Salesforce, automatically, by looking for specified "Opportunity Stages" on the Opportunity object in Salesforce. Example: When a given lead is qualified, and their stage is updated to reflect that, this now counts as a secondary conversion in AdWords.

Now I have normal conversions which measure how many people have created an account, ***and*** I can measure how many of those accounts are actually potential customers. I love this. It's automatic and gives us pretty granular insight.

The workflow is:

1. Lead clicks on search or display ad
2. Arrives at landing page, is assigned a GCLID
3. Ideally the lead signs up and self identifies
4. Code on our site sends all the lead's self-provided information PLUS their GCLID into our database AND into Salesforce, where the GCLID is retained in a separate field (called GCLID)
5. When that lead is converted to an opportunity in Salesforce, the GCLID transfers from the individual lead to the Opportunity object for the account
6. AdWords polls once daily at midnight for any opportunities where the GCLID field is filled out AND they have reached a specified stage (post qualification)
7. When AdWords polls the SFDC API and a record matches those criteria, it imports that GCLID, the date of creation, and the value (field named "Amount") that is assigned to the lead.
8. AdWords is supposed to measure that 1) the conversion occurred (which it does) and 2) the VALUE of the conversion that is determined by a field in SFDC.

I'm having trouble with step 8. I can see the AdWords import history and it's detecting the conversion AND the value, but the ***VALUE*** is not appearing in any AdWords report of any kind. All values associated with that conversion are 0, though the conversions themselves are registering.

I've now spoken with AdWords support reps directly and have solicited advice from their community forum, no luck. Anyone have any idea of why this might happen?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please review our [SO Question Checklist](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) to help you to ask a good question, and thus get a good answer.

Answer (score 0):

[Per this FAQ](https://support.google.com/adwords/answer/6299296#conversion_actions), it sounds like AdWords looks for the conversion value in the Opportunity's Expected Review field.

Comment: Owen did this answer your question?